# Java ArrayList IndexOutOfBound when reading Comments from a file

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a program that reads a file and then checks if there's an equal amount of close and open brackets. Thus what I did was use FileInputStream and the Scanner class to read the file and store each character in an ArrayList. My program works most of the time if the file read does not end with a block comment. Here is my code below.

```
private Input input;
private ArrayList<Character> fileText;

public q1_19() {
    input = new Input();
    fileText = new ArrayList<Character>();
}

private void storeTextInArray(String name) {
    FileInput readFile = new FileInput(name); //Makes use of Scanner and FileInputStream

    while(readFile.hasNextChar()) {
        fileText.add(readFile.nextChar());
    }
    readFile.close();
}

private boolean booleanChecker() {
    int braces = 0;

    boolean lineComment = false;
    boolean blockComment = false;
    boolean constant = false;
    boolean string = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < fileText.size(); i ++) {

        //Case lineComment
        if ((fileText.get(i) == '/') && (fileText.get(i+1) == '/') && ((i+1)<fileText.size())) {
            lineComment = true;
        }

        if ((lineComment) && (fileText.get(i) == '\n')) {
            lineComment = false;
        }

        //Case constant
        if ((fileText.get(i) == '\'') && (fileText.get(i+2) == '\'') && ((i+2)<fileText.size())) {
            constant = true;
            i++;
        }

        //End String
        if ((string) && (fileText.get(i) == '"')) {
            string = false;
        }

        //End blockComment
        if ((blockComment) && (fileText.get(i) == '*') && (fileText.get(i+1) == '/') && (i+1 < fileText.size())) {
            blockComment = false;
            if (fileText.lastIndexOf(fileText) == i) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!(lineComment || blockComment || constant || string)) {
            //String constant
            if (fileText.get(i) == '"') string = true;

            if ((fileText.get(i) == '/') && (fileText.get(i+1) == '*') && (i+1 < fileText.size())) blockComment = true;

            if (!(lineComment || blockComment || constant || string)) {
                if (fileText.get(i) == '{') { braces ++; System.out.println("+1"); }
                if (fileText.get(i) == '}') { braces --; System.out.println("-1"); }
                }
        }

        constant = false;
    }
    System.out.println(braces);
    if (braces != 0) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

For example, when I try to read
`{{}} 
/**/`, the errors I get are 
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)`

It's not really a problem as I can read most files but I would just like to understand why. Also please forgive me if I asked a question wrongly as this is my first question on StackFlow. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're looping from 0 to `length - 1`, yet you have `fileText.get(i + 1)`. This will go out of the array's bounds as the maximum array index is `length - 1`, and you're effectively going from 1 to `length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checks are incorrect:

```
if ((fileText.get(i) == '/') && (fileText.get(i+1) == '/') && ((i+1)<fileText.size())) {
```

It's not that the checks are missing completely, but the conditions are evaluated from left to right, so your access to `fileText.get(i+1)` happens *before* the check for the correct length is executed.

Change it to:

```
if ((fileText.get(i) == '/') && ((i+1)<fileText.size() && fileText.get(i+1) == '/')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your conditions you are checking (i+1),(i+2) at many places, where i can go upto fileText.size()-1. This will lead to outofBound Array Exception.

```
    if ((fileText.get(i) == '/') && (fileText.get(i+1) == '*') && (i+1 < fileText.size())) blockComment = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You try to access a field out of amount. Your last character is right like '/' but you try to access an other one which is not available. See code lines below

```
//Case lineComment
    if ((fileText.get(i) == '/') && (fileText.get(i+1) == '/') && ((i+1)<fileText.size())) {
        lineComment = true;
    }
```

Let's say i = fileText.size() - 1 and what will happen in case

```
fileText.get(i)   // nothing all is fine
fileText.get(i+1) // ??? occur exception IndexOutOfBound
```